# How to parse data from json(url) and send data to url

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I am trying to send data to url from where i am parsing json data and i want to know can we edit json data in url if we created random json store from myjson.com or we have to maintain our own server to edit json data.Here i created random json store and i am parsing data from that url and i also wanted to edit the data in url thats the problem i was not able to do .Its not working.please help???
This was structure

> [{"name":"pavan","hit":true}]

this was mainactivity code from where fetchdata executes in background

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button click;
    public static TextView data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        click=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        data=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fetcheddata);
        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                fetchdata process=new fetchdata();
                process.execute();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

This is fetchdata class from where fetching data from url and displaying in text view of mainactivity

```
public class fetchdata extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    String data="";
    String dataparsed="";
    String singleparsed="";
    boolean flag=false;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            URL url=new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1854yb");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line="";
            while (line!=null)
            {
                line=bufferedReader.readLine();
                data=data+line;
            }
            JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(data);
            for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject JO= (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                singleparsed="Name:"+JO.get("name")+"\n"+"Feed key:"+JO.get("hit");
                dataparsed=dataparsed+singleparsed;
            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        MainActivity.data.setText(this.dataparsed);
        JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
        try {
            postData.put("name","sai");
            postData.put("hit", false);

            new senddata().execute("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1854yb", postData.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

This is senddata to url code from postexecute of fetchdata this was executing and nothing is happening in url please help i am working on this from 3 days

```
public class senddata extends AsyncTask<String,Void, String> {

    String data="";
    String dataparsed="";
    String singleparsed="";
    boolean flag=false;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String data = "";
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        try {

            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes("PostData=" + params[1]);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
            while (inputStreamData != -1) {
                char current = (char) inputStreamData;
                inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                data += current;
            }
            dataparsed=data;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e("TAG", result);



    }

}
```

Comment: why are you using same api url for fetchdata and senddata?

Comment: try to check senddata api in Postman.i am getting 404 status code so may be there is issue in backend side

Comment: yeah i am using same api in fetchdata(fetching data from api) and  senddata(edit data in same api) and to edit does we need our own server

Answer (score 0):

This api doesn't accept any paramter after its url.
It is a get method Api url not post method . Try running it in post method in postman , it will give error.
If u run in get method ,it will produce same output ,even if u add something after url :-"https://api.myjson.com/bins/1854yb"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some issue with myJson in creating api. If you are a beginner in android your can also try with [Link for ready made Api for Android](https://reqres.in/)

They have created different kind of Apis for understanding the json concept.

also get some update about PostMan [Link for postman](https://medium.com/quick-code/top-tutorials-to-learn-postman-for-rest-api-testing-3bdf9788e0ba)